# Class Diagram - Suggestions Needed

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm learning UML. Can I get some constructive criticism on this Class Diagram.

[image]

Any suggestions for improvement? Does the cardinality make sense?

Comment: Looks like a legitimate UML diagram to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are learning UML, I recommend you to use a real modeler. It seems this diagram has been done by a drawing tool, some notations are illegal (and are nonsense) in UML:

- The correct notation for a typed elemeent is 'a : Animal' (not 'Animal a')
- The correct notation for infinite cardinality is '*' and not 'M'
- And having cardinality on a realization link is nonsense (it is not an association)

If you are using a real modeling tool, it can avoid you some mistakes and make a lot of validity check.

Comment: Does the Spawner have a dependency or an association with the Animal?

Comment: It depends what you want to say. But I think in your example an association is the good choice. An association means you can navigate for an entity to another. A dependency is a more weak link meaning an entity is depending to another entity for its specification or implementation (like an import in some programming languages).